# Extend base interface and export it

Tags: typescript

How I can to extend base interface and export it? For example:

```
export interface Date {
    /**
     * Original functions
     */
    getTime(): number;
    /**
     * My extend functions
     */
    getId(): number;

}

Date.prototype.getId = function (): number {
    return 1;
}
```

If I want to export Date prototype, I receive error

> [ts] Property 'getId' does not exist on type 'Date'.

Only I can is create manually d.ts file

```
export interface Date {
    getTime(): number;
    getId (): number;
}
```

and import it

```
import {Date} from "myfile";
```

But it's not cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add methods to the `Date` prototype you'll need [Global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation):

```
// myfile.ts

export {}; // you need this so the compiler understands that it's a module.

declare global {
    interface Date {
        getId(): number;
    }
}

Date.prototype.getId = function (): number {
    return 1;
}
```

Then when you import this file you should be able to use `getId`:

```
import "file1";
let d = new Date();
console.log(d.getId());
```

Comment: Awesome! That's what I need! Thank you!